# How to define a type from an existing type but with optional keys (not with Partial)?

Tags: typescript

I'm doing some state merging in React/Redux along the way of:

```js
const newStateSlice={
    ...state.activeData.entities[action.payload.localId],
    ...action.payload,
    isModified: true
}
```

My issue is that I want to define the type of action.payload so that it has the same exact type as a member of state.activeData.entities but with all props being optional (except localId) so that I can merge the keys I want to change and leave the rest unchanged.

Let's call this base type "Entity" and let's assume the following structure:

```js
interface Entity{
    localId: number
    a: string
    b: number | undefined
    c?: Date
}
```

What I want to get is:

```
interface PartialEntity{
    localId: number
    a?: string
    b?: number | undefined
    c?: Date
}
```

I tried the following:

```js
type PartialEntity = Partial<NewFeeds.State.ActiveFeed> & { localId: number }
```

The reason this doesn't work for me is that Partial allows the keys to have an undefined value (which I don't want to allow) so the resulting type is:

```
type PartialEntity{
    localId: number,
    a?: string | undefined,
    b?: number | undefined,
    c?: Date | undefined
}
```

I could, of course, manually write this out but I need to do this for every entity and probably again in the future and it's not very DRY... Is there some operator like Partial that does what I want?

EDIT: Turns out "c?: Date | undefined" and "c?: Date" are equivalent but what I really want is for typeScript to allow not setting the key but throw an error if it's set to undefined because undefined still overwrites my existing values when I spread an object like this:

```
const a = {prop_a: 1, prop_b: 2}
const b = {prop_a: undefined, prop_b: 3}
const c = {...a, ...b};
```

c is now:

```
{
    prop_a: undefined,
    prop_b: 3
}
```

Comment: *"... and doesn't allow those keys to be omitted..."* Yes, it does: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKLmGAngbwFDKHIA2A9gnMQJIAmAXMiAK4C2ARtAUXAwM5hRQAcy6E2DZu2jIAPsiYgaEGKAg1RyBAH4GAETiQ8AXzx5sABxQAFOFDDBK6e9mQBeZDbsPiAHieYsAD5kADJkHDIKanpGVg4oIwBuU2IIMGQADwZPe0cMF3cI8kpaBgAWACYkvCA (But it does indeed allow `undefined`.)

Comment: Yes, I just found that out by tinkering around but the fact that it allows undefined still makes it a deal breaker for me because accidentally passing undefined overwrites the existing value. Will edit the question.

Comment: I think for that you're going to need to do a runtime check. Even a manually-written type with (say) `a?: string` would allow `{a: undefined}`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKLmGAnsg3gKGSOQBsB7BOEgSQBMAuZEAVwFsAjaAbkOLgH5GAZzBRQAcx7Fk7QUzacoyAD7JmIWhBigItKcQRyAInEg8AvvnwkIYZAA9G6MJhwBePOUo0GyACwATAA0yHCM6praILrmPEA

Comment: I figured out why I was getting the typescript error (typescript was telling me I can't assign string | undefined to string) and I assumed it was because of this but it's because I didn't check if state.activeData.entities[action.payload.localId] was undefined. I still wish I could throw a TS error if someone puts a undefined value in there but I can live with this for now.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/NVnOGN) meet your needs?  If so, I'll write up an answer about how it works.  If not, could you elaborate on what I'm missing?

Comment: My issue is with how undefinedC works in your example. I want it to throw an error in that situation. Yes, c is optional, but an object without a "c" property works differently in JS than an object with a "c" property but set to undefined. To understand the problem, look at the last two code snippets of my question. If the "b" object doesn't have a "prop_a" property, the resulting object will have prop_a=1 (from object "a"), but if b has prop_a=undefined, this will overwrite the object "a" prop and the resulting object will have prop_a=undefined.

Comment: I want to set the type of object "b" so that it can have "prop_a", can omit that property, but CAN'T set it to undefined (because prop_a on the "a" object is never undefined and it should never be undefined on the "c" object)

Comment: @Supperhero - Isn't that what jcalz's code does? In his examples, you can see that `strictPartialEntity({ localId: 1, a: "hello" })` works because `a` is a string, and `strictPartialEntity({ localId: 2, b: undefined })` works because `a` isn't there at all (and `b`'s original type allows `undefined`), but `strictPartialEntity({ localId: 1, a: undefined })` fails because `a` is there with the value `undefined`, but its original type didn't allow that. Isn't that exactly what you want?

Comment: I ***think*** that if you want to specify the required property (`localId`) instead of specifying the ones you want to make optional (`a`, `b`, and `c`), [this update](https://tsplay.dev/w26Q4w) to @jcalz's code does that. I think.

Comment: @Supperhero "Yes, c is optional, but an object without a "c" property works differently in JS than an object with a "c" property but set to undefined".  But in TypeScript, an optional property allows `undefined` whether you like it or not.  You can go to [microsoft/TypeScript#13195](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195) and give it a  and explain why you have an issue.  My code is a workaround for this, and if you write `strictPartial<T, K>()` it will produce a function which only accepts objects with the keys in `K` either present-and-not-`undefined`, or missing.

Comment: I will probably write up an answer explaining all this, but if you think I'm not understanding the issue in some way, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update for TS4.4+:

There is now [an `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes) which will prevent you from *writing* `undefined` to an optional property (unless the value explicitly accepts `undefined` like your `b`).  This compiler option is not part of [the `--strict` suite of compiler features](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict) so it's not really considered "standard" the way the `strict` options are.  If you enable it, it could cause other parts of your code to error, which may or may not be acceptable.  If you do want to enable it, then it will solve your issue:

```
type Partialize<T, K extends keyof T> = Partial<Pick<T, K>> & Omit<T, K>
type PartialEntity = Partialize<Entity, "a" | "b" | "c">;

const noLocalId: PartialEntity = {}; // error
// Property 'localId' is missing in type

const definedAC: PartialEntity = { localId: 1, a: "hello", c: new Date() }; // okay

const undefinedA: PartialEntity = { localId: 1, a: undefined }; // error!
//     Types of property 'a' are incompatible.

const undefinedB: PartialEntity = { localId: 2, b: undefined }; // okay

const unexpectedD: PartialEntity = { localId: 4, d: "oops" } // error!
// Object literal may only specify known properties
```

If you don't want to enable it or are using TS4.3-, then see the original answer below.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKLmGAnsg3gKGSOQBsB7BOEgSQBMAuZEAVwFsAjaQ4uRgZzBRQAc25F2jFh2jIAPsmYhaEGKAi0xyBIwAicSPgC++fNgAOKAApwoYYFWAAvCAB4AKgBpkAaWQQAHpBKfMgA1hBYZDDIbgB8yAC8yNa29iQulsAIoe5e3rHxAGTIAPKsmLk+saZYFsk2dlTodtiJ9akOzi7NmFheAERw-XLI-ezD8v0I-bEA3CYIZCACTGQAMhRUdIwpjSQ9rUm4hrPIAPRnflBQZFD4F8k3FrY4AOTklDS0r8jAIeV8PgiX4gZDmCALJYrZSqEDqACCAGEdg00gccEdSJsvowAIxeXijAAWEBI5H6Xm0TAgAHdkHpIAAKACUyBO50uZFCcCwkOWYAUShUalo8JRHX2GEOeCxn22yHxyEJihhIrZpwe0BuUAAhPdLsQYrUICEosgzE9oK1XnAfjYUKBFqwzPpgOwSBAAHR8lYq4Vw2gAIXFe3RbVwsq2DGQACYvBJBaqA+qOcguTyfQLFAELAhILQdCG0VKMTKPlHGAAWLzR-pkMhmPjDQyprW3PUPErsABWEDzpEw0CoyFYPLTIBIOD4ueAMBwoRAZBpoItDatwBNJiAA)

---

Original answer:

You've discovered that TypeScript doesn't do a perfect job of telling the difference between a property which is *missing* from one which is *present* but whose value is `undefined`.  From the point of view of just reading one of these properties, there really *is* no difference. `foo.bar === undefined` will be `true` in either case.  But of course, there are situations where there is a noticeable difference, such as when you spread an object, or even a simple test like `"bar" in foo`.  This mismatch between the TypeScript type system and the behavior of Javascript is a longstanding open issue; see [microsoft/TypeScript#13195](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195) for a lengthy discussion.  If you want to see this addressed, you could give it a , but it's not clear to me if or when this will ever happen.

For the time being, there are workarounds.

---

The workaround I recommend here is to avoid the built-in [optional property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) functionality, and instead make a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) helper function that, for the properties that *would* be optional, accepts a value without any such property, or a value with a non-`undefined` property.  It looks something like this:

```
const strictPartial = <T, K extends keyof T>() =>
    <U extends {
        [P in keyof U]-?: P extends keyof T ? T[P] : never
    } & Omit<T, K>>(u: U) => u;
```

The `strictPartial()` function is a [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) function.  It takes a two type parameters: `T`, the object type in question (with no optional properties), and `K`, the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of keys you'd like to make "optional" in the way I described above.  It then outputs a new function which only accepts objects of such a "strict partial" type. The return value of *that* function is the same as its input, so the compiler keeps track of which properties are actually present.

If you inspect the [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) on the `U` type parameter, you'll see that it is the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of `Omit<T, K>`, a type with all the properties of `T` not mentioned in `K`, and a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) where every property from `U` is either matched with its property from `T`, or is `never`.  We will explore how that works below.

---

Here it is for the particular `Entity` type:

```
interface Entity {
    localId: number
    a: string
    b: number | undefined
    c: Date // <-- this is no longer optional, as mentioned above
}

const strictPartialEntity = strictPartial<Entity, "a" | "b" | "c">();
/* const strictPartialEntity: <U extends 
  { [P in keyof U]-?: P extends keyof Entity ? Entity[P] : never; } & 
  Omit<Entity, "a" | "b" | "c">>(u: U) => U */
```

So `strictPartialEntity()` is a function that takes an object of type `U`.  This `U` type is like `Entity`, except that `a`, `b`, and `c` properties are now "optional".  You must pass in a `localId` of type `number` (`Omit<Entity, "a" | "b" | "c">` is equivalent to `{localId: number}`).  You are allowed to leave out `a`, `b`, and `c` properties entirely (any key you leave out is not in `keyof U`, so `[P in keyof U]` will ignore it), or specify them as the right types (any key `P` you put in must match `keyof Entity`, and its value must match the same type, `Entity[P]`... or else it must match `never` which is impossible).

Note that only `b` will accept `undefined`, and that's because `b` is explicitly typed to allow it in `Entity`.

Let's make sure it behaves that way:

```
const noLocalId = strictPartialEntity({}); // error! 
// Property 'localId' is missing ---> ~~

const definedAC = strictPartialEntity(
    { localId: 1, a: "hello", c: new Date() }) // okay

const undefinedA = strictPartialEntity(
    { localId: 1, a: undefined }) // error! 
// -------------> ~
// Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'

const undefinedB = strictPartialEntity(
    { localId: 2, b: undefined }) // okay, 
// b explicitly allows undefined

const unexpectedD = strictPartialEntity(
    { localId: 4, d: "oops" }) // error!
// -------------> ~
//  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'

const fullEntity: Entity = {
    ...definedAC,
    ...undefinedB
} // okay
```

That all behaves correctly.  The compiler complains about `undefined` for `a`, but not for `b`.  And the compiler recognizes that `fullEntity` is in fact an `Entity`, because it sees that `definedAC` and `undefinedB` together have all the properties of `Entity`.

---

As I said, this is a workaround to [microsoft/TypeScript#13195](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195).  It's more complicated than we'd like because it struggles to express something that TypeScript doesn't make easy: that there is a difference between `undefined` and missing.  The helper functions and generics are an unfortunate necessity if you want to try to do this.

The other way to approach this is to embrace TypeScript's inability to tell the difference, and defensively code against `undefined`. I'm not going to go into details here, since this is already quite a long answer. But, as a sketch: you could write a function like `stripUndefined` which iterates over an object's properties and removes any properties whose value is `undefined`.  If you spread the output of *that* function, you don't have to worry anymore about a rogue `undefined` actually overwriting another property.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ssl=34&ssc=41&pln=33&pc=41#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKLmGAnsg3gKGSOQBsB7BOEgSQBMAuZEAVwFsAjaQ4uRgZzBRQAc25F2jFh2jIAPsmYhaEGKAi0xyBIwAicSPgC++fAjIgByAUIRgACnChhgVZAF5kAHgAqAGmQA0sgQAB6QSnzIANYQWGQwyN4AfAAUAJTuSZqeAKrBYRAReJrEyADadsig0bHxyDkAugC0APyMlaHhtJExcQneyC2JFQ3IkhAAblylhsgAZMgA8qyYPv4BSanMjDkZbkkKANwmZhZgVoLAtg5OLiToztjuFzb2js5Ung+YWP4ARHA-nJkH92ED5H8EH9UmljgB6ABUWnMlmsVzetyo32wjFy+S6kW4uHKlWqvTqjVa7XxhW6NT6aAwTyG2KwIzGTEm0EOyFmC24y1WrP+gOBoPBIKhmxS23qewOeQRcJOKPOIDIABkKFQ6M80dd3ndWSlcIZYcg4XDglAoGQoABCZD4S3IOy2gAO0CeAHJyJQaLRvVVIis+HwRMgmlGDgA-GMqs7IZSqEDqACCAGE9ZcDZj7kysClNMS-TqGMgAIz+XgggAWEBI5D+-m0nIA7sg9JB0ryMi6yFE4FgE5ZFMm1LQ09nXjcPvnHoXi6RtQHGFXkDWxyoJ72LVboLaHU6XVHT2ez7HnVbvFhPchvVuU+og8BIurznAw8BhCA4OwSCgYBkMg2B3t6aIgMI3ojucj4TgAQtO6KzkaBZFqUJYrnQjAAEz+BIChKNuqa0Lu-aDr8x5Wuw+TuiQVyYCQOBUOQbaRHBJEwYRoSerY6g6EhuZzsaS6lquyAACz+OWfxkGQ7p8ECZp7tah72lekbnlpTSXi6iS3ig4GXJBL5vmQH5fj+f4ASBwGgYZqZTFA0GmKqyAwMwjasowrLPAQpQAHRBeOJGZr4mhBQFHHqPBRgqQOQ4mPgHkgLYwDmC8wDujkRFPrQPg0kUZDsAAVhAtipGAjDeGk1XFKUUAQGAzBQCASyleVYABTAtqsA8QgQHwKSLB1tgBYUlyDSkYBpN1wAkJAUApCkZRRP4EwNPKyATMg9puB40W0GkGSfhuIDMZE3hGEAA)

Comment: Thanks for the very well written answer.  @T.J.Crowder I would assume they are talking about the same issue I ran across (as explained in my post) where, when you destructure two objects with some shared properties into one, if the second object is missing a property the first object has, that property will not be overwritten, but if the second object has that property set as undefined, the resulting object will have it as undefined even if it had a different value in the first object. [example code](https://playcode.io/756419/)

Comment: @Supperhero - That's not destructuring, that's spreading. This is destructuring: https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/4p6zyn9m/ (But you could well be right, spread does extract properties from objects...)

Comment: Oof, I meant spread and not destructure.  Sorry!

Comment: Yeah, got my phrases mixed up, my bad. I'll edit the question to make that clearer.

Comment: This answer might be outdated for TypeScript 4.4+. The new compiler option `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` does not allow explicitly setting an optional property to `undefined`. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exactOptionalPropertyTypes