# Is there a way to pass one generic and infer another?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

consider the following code:

```
const selectFrom =
  <T>() =>
  <U extends Partial<T>>(fields: U) => {
    return fields as U;
  };

type Item = { a: string; b: string };

// intellisense on the argument Partial<Item>
const x = selectFrom<Item>()({ a: "" });
// typeof x => { a: string }
```

I'm able to have the types I want only if `selectFrom` returns another function. Is there a way to achieve the below target signature?

```
// target signature:
const x = selectFrom<Item>({ a: "" });

// current signature:
const x = selectFrom<Item>()({ a: "" });
```

Comment: Why doesn't `const selectFrom = <T>(v:Partial<T>) ...` fit here?

Comment: @spender - That would result in `Partial<T>` for the given example, not `{a: string;}` as the current code provides. (See the difference [here](https://tsplay.dev/WvV5QW).)

Comment: @​Maciej - I'm fairly sure you need that intermediary function. (There are a few places where that's necessary; the answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66989064/), for instance.) But I'm only at the journeyman level in TypeScript so far, so I'm not sure enough to post that as an answer. :-) Watching with interest!

Answer (score 2):

What you want to achieve is currently not possible (*kind of* possible, see below).

However, if you are willing to bear with an extra variable for each of the instantiations of `T`, you can separate the function signature from the implementation and  move the `T` type parameter to be a type alias's required type parameter while keeping the rest of the signature generic and constrained to `Partial<T>`:

```js
type selectFrom<T> = <U extends Partial<T>>(fields: U) => U;

type Item = { a: string; b: string };

type Item2 = { answer: 42, question: unknown };

const selectFromI: selectFrom<Item> = (fields) => fields;
const selectFromJ: selectFrom<Item2> = (fields) => fields;

// intellisense on the argument Partial<Item>
const y = selectFromI({ a: "" });
//    ^? const y: { a: string; }
const x = selectFromJ({ answer: 42 });
//    ^? const x: { answer: 42; }
```

It is not ideal, but at least you do not need to make an extra "hollow" call every time you want to use the `selectFrom` function (and you are likely to find yourself wanting to extract the first call into a variable anyways).

On a related note, TypeScript 4.7 is getting [instantiation expressions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7/#instantiation-expressions) that, although unfortunately do not allow for your use case, seem to be a step in the direction of allowing partial application of generic type parameters.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mb0oow)